# Language spelling menu switch

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

I understand that Mac OsX should recognise the language automatically - and to say the honest truth - it does but... on rare occasions I need to see which language in"ON" and what are the choices...

Menu indicator-switch would be of great help - maybe an extra function to the keyboard indicator would solve the problem.

I use 4 languages in many programs...

Comment: The choices used by the "automatic" setting in system prefs/keyboard/text/spelling are normally determined by the boxes you check in the Setup item of that menu.

Comment: Perhaps best not to use "automatic" and just switch among you four specific languages via Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar in each app.

Answer (score 1):

One way to maximize the ease of changing the spellcheck language is to use an app which allows you to synchronize the keyboard layout and the spellcheck dictionary.  I think both Nisus Writer and Mellel have this feature.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to see your selected lanugate in your menu bar if you have the option turned on.

In System Preferences > Keyboard, make sure you have the option "Show Input Menu in Menu Bar" checked

[image]

Your Menu Bar should now show a flag with the corresponding language

[image]

When you click on it, you should get a selection of the input sources you currently have available.

[image]

Comment: The question has nothing to do with input sources, but concerns the spellcheck language, which is determined elsewhere.  You should delete this.

Comment: @TomGewecke   How did you determine that since it's no where in the OP's question?

Comment: Because the word "spelling" is in the subject line and automatic language recognition really can only refer to spellcheck.